# Segmentation Fault 11 with Maps and vector c++

Tags: c++11, dictionary, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to get a frequency table from a given text. 
But the output is showing segmentation fault 11. I don't know why. 
I am a newbie. Your help with the code will be very well appreciated. 
You can edit my code to make me learn a better method of writing code as well. Thanks a lot.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

void make_table(vector<pair<char, int> > &table , string path){
    string text = "Hello thusnvkj.ernbuilvgqboipghq3pojavnaj.,fbvlkarebihfg094why091[3tugjvlksbdfv  ajklvrpt-30qjhrgiaoehk.BL;H]IH;LGBJSFDNOWI;HBPWRHGB;ORTWIHGOQHRWI0TUGJRLKEWHUGIH49P0-IT302-UR9GM,NXM,BNX,MNMB/E/RGP'KGP34OR[2=O-O-=0-3-1I0-439890375892R0U;L.GNLS.N.SVMS/FS/FKWEP[IF0W))_*(&*(^^&$%#^%$&%*(^*&)(*)_*_(()())))]]'";
    map<char, int> m;
    for(int i=0; text[i]!='\0'; i++){
        m[text[i]]++;
    }
    map<char,int>::iterator it;
    int j=0;
    for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end(); it++){
        table[j].first=it->first;
        table[j].second=it->second;
        j++;
        //cout << it->first << "   " << it->second << endl;
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    vector<pair<char , int> > table;
    string path;
    //cin >> path;
    path= "Hi";
    make_table(table, path);
    // make_table function will give us the sorted table(vector of pair) in the decreasing order of frequency of a character.
    /*for(int i =0; i<table.size(); i++){
        cout << table[i].first << "     " << table[i].second << endl;
    }
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because you try to access elements in an empty vector

```
table[j].first=it->first;
table[j].second=it->second;
```

Here you can add one line outside the for loop

```
table.resize(text.size());
```